# Retrieve thymeleaf object value from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have simple thymeleaf template gets objects from controller, in that template I have select with options coming from controller as an array/list, want to access the selected option's value. But I am getting memory reference as string from JavaScript

Controller:

```
modelAndView.addObject("banks",screenDetail.getBanks().toArray());
```

HTML:

```
<select id="chooseBank" name="bankId" style="width:100%" class="de-intl-select" onchange="handleBank()">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option th:each="bank:${banks}" th:text="${bank.name}"
            th:value="${bank}">
    </option>
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
function handleBank()
{
    var chooseBankField = document.getElementById('chooseBank');
    var bank = chooseBankField.options[chooseBankField.selectedIndex].value;
    console.log("PRINT: "+ bank);
    console.log("PRINT: "+ bank.id);
}
```

first its prints the object reference as sting, i,e com.test.Bank@L1232142
Second line print undefined.

Note: Bank is pojo with fields like id, name, logo etc.

Where I am going wring here ?

Comment: Why the "java" tag? http://javascriptisnotjava.com/

Comment: You have a typo in your code `console.log("PRINT: "+ bakn.id);`. It should be `bank` not `bakn`.

Comment: Yes that's a typo, but it did not exist in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use ${bank.value} in `th:value` or override `toString()` in the Bank class. What you get is the result of the default implementation of the `toString()` method.

Comment: ${bank.value}  tries to access if any field defined with the name 'value'. So its returning undefined. But toString() method sounds might work will give it a try. But I am trying to understand why simply from JavaScript this object can not be accessible? I have used "<script th:inline="javascript" " this too

Comment: Yes having a toString method returning josn solved it.